# Why pagination from material.angular don't work? (Angular 5)

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

I have the data list with pagination which supports of customizing amount Items per page. For the start, I use the [official example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dmdknoynvle?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts) from `material.angular.io`.
But in my code pagination don't work. Angular lost pagination object. And when I change `Items per page` value from IU noting todo. Pagination settings don't work, I have 2000 elements on the page. All data from server render on one table page.

```
<div *ngIf="dataIsLoaded">
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ip">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> IP</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.ip}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="password">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Password</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.password}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Start Date</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.activatedDate}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="endDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> End Date</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.deactivatedDate}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Detail button -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="detail">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Detail</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="getDetail(row.id)">Detail</button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
      </mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator #paginator
                   [pageSize]="10"
                   [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]"
                   [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
    </mat-paginator>

  </div>
</div>
```

And TS side:

```
export class VdsListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = [
    'id',
    'ip',
    'password',
    'startDate',
    'endDate',
    'detail'
  ];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Vds>;
  filterForm: FormGroup;
  dataIsLoaded = false;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private vdsService: VdsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterForm = new FormGroup({
      'ip': new FormControl(null, []),
      'id': new FormControl(null, []),
      'dateFrom': new FormControl(null, []),
      'dateTo': new FormControl(null, [])
    });

    this.vdsService.getVds().subscribe((vds: Vds[]) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(vds);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataIsLoaded = true;
    });
  }

}
```

Now does not console error.

Help me understand why my code doesn't work and fix it.

Comment: The error message says it all: you're trying to set paginator on this.dataSource, but this.dataSource is undefined at that point, since it's only initialized later, when the callback to the asynchronous observable returned by this.vdsService.getVds() emits.

Comment: @JB Nizet I update question. In the start, I set paginator into ngOnInit() and don't get the error, but pagination does not work and I do how in the official example - move set paginator into ngAfterViewInit() and get this error. I returned set paginator in ngOnInit(). Now console is clear, but pagination doesn't work. All data on one page.

Comment: The paginator needs the view to be there to be defined, since it's a ViewChild. The view isn't there yet in ngOnInit. Your initial code was less buggy than the new one. Read what I told in my comment instead of trying random things.

Comment: @JB Nizet I understand! Paginator does not exist not in ngOnInit(). I need set paginator after build view. But where? I thought ngAfterViewInit() call after view initialized. How to know about ViewChild will be inited?

Comment: It is. But read the error message, and read my comment. The problem is not that paginator is undefined. It is, when used inside ngAfterViewInit. Wht is undefined is `this.dataSource`. Hence the error: `Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined`, when trying to execute `this.dataSource.paginator = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolve with setter and initializing `dataSource`:

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Vds> = new MatTableDataSource([]);

paginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild(MatPaginator)
set appBacon(paginator: MatPaginator) {
  this.paginator = paginator;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
constructor(private vdsService: VdsService) {
}
ngOnInit() {   
  this.filterForm = new FormGroup({
    'ip': new FormControl(null, []),
    'id': new FormControl(null, []),
    'dateFrom': new FormControl(null, []),
    'dateTo': new FormControl(null, [])
  });

  this.vdsService.getVds().subscribe((vds: Vds[]) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(vds);
      this.dataIsLoaded = true;
    });
}
```

Thanks to *JB Nizet* for patience)